# How to resolve TypeError: this.state.person is undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hey I am new to react so I am currently learning on about state so I am failing to understand why when I run the code it compiles however when in the browser I get the following error can you please help me understand where I could be going wrong with all this.

**Code Below**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';


class App extends Component{

    state = [{
        person :[{

            name: 'Junior',
            age: 19,
            country: 'South Africa'

        }, {

            name: 'Max',
            age:25,
            country: 'America'

        }, {

            name: 'Angel',
            age: 55,
            country: 'Germany'

        }]
    }]

    switchNameHandler = () =>{

        this.setState({ 
            person :[{

                name: 'BEn',
                age: 19,
                country: 'South Africa'

            }, {

                name: 'Max',
                age:25,
                country: 'America'

            }, {

                name: 'Angel',
                age: 55,
                country: 'Germany'

            }]})
    

    }

    render(){
        return(

            <div>
                <button onClick{this.switchNameHandler}/>
                <Todo name={this.state.person[0].name} age={this.state.person[0].age} country=    {this.state.person[0].country}/>
                <Todo name={this.state.person[1].name} age={this.state.person[1].age} country={this.state.person[1].country}/>
                <Todo name={this.state.person[2].name} age={this.state.person[2].age} country={this.state.person[2].country}/>
        
           
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: Your state is an array. So you need to specify the index: `this.state[0].person`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading too much into it. State has no magical properties besides the fact that it is immutable.

You are simply using the wrong data structures.

You are setting your initial state with an array that has a single object with a nested array of 'person' objects. Instead of troubleshooting why you are not understanding the react state, you should be thinking about how you can use the data structure you have created.

```
this.state[0].person[0].name
```

That would get you what you are looking for. It is not the most elegant way of access this data (even if you intended to iterate over it).

Based on how you are trying to access your state you should remap it as so:

```
state = { person: [{name: '', age: '', country: ''}] }
```

Don't overthink react and state. It is just Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

From initial state, you can remove the [] from state to make it work. State is supposed to be object.

```
   state = {
    person :[{

        name: 'Junior',
        age: 19,
        country: 'South Africa'

    }, {

        name: 'Max',
        age:25,
        country: 'America'

    }, {

        name: 'Angel',
        age: 55,
        country: 'Germany'

    }]
}
```